# Why custom control's timer was slow when main form event enter?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

I was created custom timer control for time count that count time max to min.And add this control to main form.In main form Key Up event,Total mark add one by checking this timer count when user click enter.The problem is when user click enter quickly repeated,the timer control's time count become slower.(I tested click enter 250 times will late 2 second).So what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The timer is not precise. It suspends for a while, at least the time set on the timer, probably longer. When the program is ready (in this case probably delayed by clicking the button), it will resume the timer. The timer action might also delay the actual execution of the timer.

Comment: ,So can i delegate the main form key up event and timer's tick event?

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: I mean,The timer control's tick event will not slow until the user click enter quickly repeat.I already try tick by thread but still not working.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The timer is not precise by definition, you are not going to change that.

Comment: I just want to time count from max to min.If you have any other knowledge,please light up me.:)